# postgresql error during pg_dump invalid value for parameter "default_tablespace": "tbs_db1_index"

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

Can someone help me please? :)
Ive 2 servers, want to split databases in exclusive instances, so im migrating my databases 1 by 1 to second server
Postgres version 11.16 both servers 
so here's my command on s1
`pg_dump db1 > /tmp/db1.dump`
then i restore on my s2:
`psql -p 5432 db1 < /tmp/db1.dump`
then i get this error 
`error: invalid value for parameter "default_tablestapce": "tbs_db1_index"`
`DETAIL: Tablespace "tbs_db1_index" does not exist`
[image]
Thing is, db1 location on s1 is not the same as at s2, this might be the problem since i have no errors or any problems on s1 my db are fine
Also, restore process doesnt stop or breaks it is still in process(my db is huge)
PS and yes, i can do this directly without dumping file by this command
pg_dump --no-owner db1 | psql -p 5432 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -h 192.168.1.2 -U postgres db1
but doesnt work either

Comment: So, what do you want to do?  Preserve the tablespaces structure?  Get rid of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tablespaces are not part of any database, so they are not included in `pg_dump` output. If you want to dump and restore the tablespaces as well, use `pg_dumpall -t` in addition of the `pg_dump` you are performing (and restore the tablespaces first). If you want to ignore the tablespaces in the dump, use `pg_dump --no-tablespaces`.

Comment: thanks, this helped

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved this:
drop existing tbs_db1_index AND tbs_db1_data (EVEN IF ITS EMPTY!), because when u create database this file are created in db directory
create new tablespaces with name as in old server
then this command works without problems on old server(s1) 
`pg_dump --no-owner db1 | psql -p 5432 -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -h 192.168.1.2 -U postgres db1`
where 192.168.1.2 - address of targeted server, in my case its s2